# NSURLConnection requests from multiple methods - getting a callback to starter method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection

I have a few methods that are posting data to a server. I am using NSURLConnection asynchronously. I am using a class variable NSMutableData and this is created in the viewDidLoad.

I have one method connection created for login and one for registration. Both just return a success booleon in response.

My question is, when the connection is complete and I receive my response, is there anyway to know which method started the connection? I.e some kind of callback to say that the login method started the connection.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you start the connection, store a reference to the `NSURLConnection` object. When the connection finishes it will pass you the connection object as a parameter, which you can check like so:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    if (connection==loginConnection) {

    } else if (connection==regConnection) {

    }
}
```

The other (possibly better) option is to offload all of the HTTP connection handling to a separate wrapper class. You can build your own from your existing code, or use a third-party one like [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) or [GTM HTTP Fetcher](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-http-fetcher/).

Comment: Thanks Graham! If I extend my class to say 7/8 different methods is keeping 7/8 connection variables a bit over kill? I thought there maybe a simpler approach